# Group Columns based on Row ID

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table pulling data, like:

```
ID    FID   Value
001   20    200
001   20    400
001   50    600
002   50    100
```

**How do write a query to get a column for each row ID that would sum the `Value`'s?**

For example, I want to return the following:

```
ID     20     50
001    600    600
002    NULL   100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pattern like this:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN FID = 20 THEN Value END) as sum20,
  SUM(CASE WHEN FID = 50 THEN Value END) as sum50 --extend by adding more CASE WHEN rows
FROM
  table
GROUP BY ID
```

..has the advantage of working in databases that don't support PIVOT syntax.

If you'd like PIVOT syntax:

```
SELECT ID, [20], [50] --extend by providing more values in square brackets
FROM
  table
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Value)
  FOR FID IN ([20], [50]) --extend by providing more values in square brackets
) pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have dynamic list of FID's you can use dynamic query as below:

```
Declare @cols1 varchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols1 = stuff((select Distinct ','+QuoteName(Fid) from #data for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Set @query = '  Select * from (
    Select Id, [Fid], [Value] from #data ) a
 pivot (sum([Value]) for [Fid] in (' + @cols1 + ') ) p '

Exec sp_executesql @query
```